# Signature Error while updating S3 object metadata through boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a lambda function that takes S3 object from S3 events and updates it with the custom metadata.

Here is the boto3 script:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    key_name = key.split('/')
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    print(key)
    print(bucket)
    s3_object = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    s3_object.metadata.update({'Cache-Control':'no-cache'})
    s3_object.copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket':bucket, 'Key':key}, Metadata=s3_object.metadata, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```

When I run the script, it gives me the following error:

> An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the CopyObject operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.: ClientError

(Note: I have given sufficient permission on lambda function role)

Do I need to create Signature here?

Comment: I think it means that your Access Key and Secret Key aren't right (although it _is_ a strange error message). Have you been able to make any other API calls via boto3 or the AWS CLI from the same computer?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have added the AdministratorAccess for this test purpose. But, no luck. same error. Is there anything I need to add on the boto3 resource definition that is related to signature?

Comment: Are you able to use the AWS CLI on the same computer? For example, `aws s3 ls`? If this fails, then it suggests that you have saved an invalid set of credentials.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah, checked it. the credentials are working perfectly.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that this is an AWS Lambda function. Sorry -- this would have nothing to do with your local credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the Key of the object has some strange characters in it.

Here is some slightly modified code that worked for me:

```py
import boto3
import urllib

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    s3_object = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    s3_object.metadata.update({'Cache-Control':'no-cache'})
    s3_object.copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket':bucket, 'Key':key}, Metadata=s3_object.metadata, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```

Answer (score 1):

John Rotenstein's answers works, but only ONCE. Running the same script twice reproduces the error OP had.

I believe this is related to why:

> User-defined metadata is a set of key-value pairs. Amazon S3 stores user-defined metadata keys in lowercase.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html

Notice that although Amazon stores keys as lowercase, OP is using upper case. Changing the "Cache-Control" to the lowercase "cache-control" will allow you to update metadata on objects where "cache-control" is already a metadatum entry.

I have tested the case sensitive issue and am able to get things working without the capitalization of the key, and reproduce the issue when the key capitalization is reintroduced.

There appears to be a discrepancy on how the signature is calculated on the client end and on the API backend at AWS. The capitalization issue only expresses itself when the metadatum entry is pre-existing on the object. This might warrant raising a ticket with AWS regarding the boto3 library.